# Asp .net hidden field can't set value with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I can't set the value of a hidden field with jquery in asp .net.

My hidden field is declared like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSelectedTicket" />
```

And this is how I set the value:

```
            alert(ticketID);
            $('#<%=hdnSelectedTicket.ClientID %>').val(ticketID);
            alert($('#<%=hdnSelectedTicket.ClientID %>').val());
```

Both alerts show the right value but when I fetch it at the server it is empty.

Comment: Everything looks ok on that code, what about the code behind ? - maybe there is the issue ?

Comment: What does your server side code look like when you're retrieving the value?

Comment: I access it like this: string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnSelectedTicket.Value). And when check the value it is an empty string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that I was putting the hidden field inside a div that was used as a model for jquery dialog. When I removed the hidden field from the div and place it somewhere else it worked.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This was the answer to my problem as well!

Comment: As long as the field is within the <form> tag, it should be returned properly.

Answer (score 20):

Set `ClientIDMode="Static"` and then you can use `$('#hdnSelectedTicket').val(ticketID);` to set the value in asp hidden field

like

```
asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedTicket" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
```

and

```
$('#hdnSelectedTicket').val(ticketID);
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending when you are reading the value on the server side, it might not be updated on the control yet - essentially if you are doing it in a change event handler, and the control that raises the change event gets updated before the hidden control, then calling hdnSelectedTicket.Value can still return the old value.

The easiest way to get around this issue is to cheat and get it straight from the Form collection:

```
var ticketId = Request.Form[hdnSelectedTicket.UniqueID];
```